# Highlighted message in command prompt when running test on K6

Tags: k6

I'm studying the execution of performance tests using K6.

Doing the Postman login test scenario, the result was positive:

[Running the test with Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIG7O.png)

I exported the Postman collection and did the file conversion for K6 to recognize it.

Then, when running the test through K6, the following is returned:

[Running the test with K6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76YDO.png)

This detail caught my attention:

✗ Successful POST request
↳  0% — ✓ 0 / ✗ 1

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Edit: This is the print with the complete result after running the test.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzcJr.png)

Edit 2: I'm putting the generated script that is being executed by K6, hiding only the address and login information:

```
// Auto-generated by the postman-to-k6 converter

import "./libs/shim/core.js";
import "./libs/shim/expect.js";

export let options = { maxRedirects: 4 };

const Request = Symbol.for("request");
postman[Symbol.for("initial")]({
  options
});

export default function() {
  postman[Request]({
    name: "New Request",
    id: "2140438e-8869-4836-ae80-7c5845d09572",
    method: "POST",
    address: "https://xxxx-xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxx/public/auth/signin",
    data: '{\r\n  "username": "xxxxxxxxxxx",\r\n  "password": "xxxxxx"\r\n}',
    post(response) {
      pm.test("Successful POST request", function() {
        pm.expect(pm.response.code).to.be.oneOf([201, 202]);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you post the final script you are running as well?

Comment: I put the print with the result in the description. Thanks!

Comment: What is the content of your k6 script?

Comment: What is the content of your k6 script? (as text, not as screenshots. Text should always be text!)

Comment: I put the k6 script in the description. Thanks!

Comment: I would guess that postman adds `Content-encoding: applicaton/json` while `k6` will not just do that. So if you add `header: {Content-Encoding: "application/json"}` it should work